# How to detect the specific wallet provider used by the user in a web3 dapp when multiple wallet providers are installed?

Tags: metamask, wallets, javascript, dapps

I want to detect which wallet provider has been used to connect to a specific dApp.

right now what I'm doing is

```
const ethereum = window.ethereum;
const web3 = window.web3;

if (ethereum && ethereum.isMetaMask) {
  console.log('Connected to MetaMask');
} else if (web3 && web3.currentProvider && web3.currentProvider.isCoinbaseWallet) {
  console.log('Connected to Coinbase Wallet');
} else if (web3 && web3.currentProvider && web3.currentProvider.isWalletConnect) {
  console.log('Connected to WalletConnect');
} else {
  console.log('Connected to an unknown wallet provider');
}
```

but the problem with this approach is, I can't detect which particular wallet has been used to connect to the dApp. When the user has multiple wallet providers installed, both `ethereum.isMetaMask` and `web3.currentProvider.isCoinbaseWallet may be true, so the above code cannot determine which specific wallet provider was used to connecting to the dapp.

Is there a way to detect the specific wallet provider used by the user when multiple wallet providers are installed? Can I listen for events or access properties to determine the specific wallet provider used by the user?

Answer (score 1):

##### This is atm natively not possible.

**You could go the other way around:**

The way [sushi](https://www.sushi.com/swap) solved this, is by asking you to before connecting which provider you want to use. After choosing, they will open the corresponding wallet provider. Sushi uses [use-wallet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-wallet) for that. If you are interested doing it natively, you can check out the [use-wallet](https://github.com/aragon/use-wallet) source code.

---

**If you don't care about using a third-party service:**

There is an awesome service called [`WalletConnect`](https://walletconnect.com/) that does this automatically for you. Every wallet I know [supports it](https://explorer.walletconnect.com/) and it has a good [documentation](https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/) as well as an easy API. It also provides either a [standardized UI](https://docs.walletconnect.com/2.0/web3modal/about) for easy user recognition but there is also the option that leaves the frontend up to you.

You will just interact with a unified API and don't have to care about the underlying wallet provider anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the comment bro. But in my use case, I want to know the wallet provider, without any 3rd party library. I need to write a script that does the same with the native browser APIs.

Comment: Updated the comment accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The code you share only checks which wallets are available in the browser.

When the user selects which wallet to use, he/she clicks a button with Metamask/coinbase/walletconnect logo, and your code will know what wallet is chosen.

When the user sends an tx, your front-end code sends the following [request](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1193):

```
Provider.request(args: RequestArguments): Promise<unknown>;
```

You should be able to check the provider by calling

- provider.isMetaMask
- provider.isCoinbaseWallet
- provider.isWalletConnect